# How can i fix the error Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: when i run rails new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf0lE.png)

i'm just triying to do a new rails app with 'rails new app', that its, install all good, but when it going to install rails webpacker:install this happened.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIgpa.jpg)

and show the next error "Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: "

Some one has the same issue and how you fix it?? thank you.

Answer (score -2):

can you please try with these steps:

Please remove `require 'bootsnap/setup'` from `config/boot.rb` and `bootsnap` from Gemfile.

And try run it again.

Comment: ok, i did, LoadError: cannot load such file -- loofah and showed me this error.